# The closure of $C_c$ in $L^\infty$ is $C_0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space that is $\sigma$-compact, and let $\mu$ be a Randon measure. Show that the closure of $C_c(X\to\mathbb{R})$ in $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is $C_0(X\to\mathbb{R})$, the space of continuous real-valued functions which vanish at infinity. (i.e. for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact $K$ such that $|f(x)|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $x\in X\setminus K$).

Given $f\in C_0(X\to\mathbb{R})$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$  there is exist a compact set $K$ such that $|f(x)|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $x\in X\setminus K$. For fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we can define a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x):=\begin{cases} x+\varepsilon,& \text{if}\ x< -\varepsilon,\\
0,&\text{if}\  -\varepsilon\leq x\leq\varepsilon,\\
x-\varepsilon,&\text{if}\ x>\varepsilon.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the function $h=g\circ f$ is continuous and supported on $K$ , thus $h\in C_c(X\to\mathbb{R})$. And we also have
$\|f-h\|_{L^\infty}\leq \varepsilon$. Now if we can prove $C_0(X\to\mathbb{R})$ is closed, we will complete the proof, but I have difficulty in proving this.

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $C_0(X\to\mathbb{R})$ that converges to a limit $f$ in $L^\infty(X,\mu)$, then $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly outside of a null-set. How to show that there is a modification of $f$ on a null-set that is continuous and vanishs at infinity. The hint tell me to use Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: Would a sketch that only works as written in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be of use?

Comment: @Ian Your answer has been deleted, I cannot see it.

Comment: I know, because I noticed that you were talking about $X$ LCH, and my proof was written for $\mathbb{R}$ (easily modified to $\mathbb{R}^n$, though).

Comment: @Ian We may prove the simple case first, could you tell you how to prove this if $X=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean that the closure of $C_0(X)$ - the space of functions that vanish at infinity - in the norm $L^\infty$ is $C_c(X)$, right?

Comment: @JohnMartin No, note that $C_c$ is contained in $C_0$, not the reverse.

Comment: Yes, I have reversed the notations, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

In general $\left \| f \right \|_\infty \leq  \left \| f \right \|_u$ but if $f$ is continuous $\left \| f \right \|_\infty =\left \| f \right \|_u := \sup_{x \in X} |f|$, since $\lbrace x: |f(x)| > M \rbrace$ is clearly an open, and it's easy to verify that a not emtpy open has always positive measure, therefore $\mu (\lbrace x: |f(x)| > M \rbrace ) = 0$ if and only if $\lbrace x: |f(x)| > M \rbrace = \emptyset$, i.e. $\left \| f \right \|_\infty =  \left \| f \right \|_u$. Then it is sufficient to demonstrate the problem for $\left \| \cdot \right \|_u$.  We know that $C_c(X) \subset C_0(X)$. We show that the closure of $C_c(X)$ in the uniform norm or sup norm is $C_0(X)$. If  $\lbrace f_k \rbrace \subset C_c(X)$ is a sequence that converge uniformly to$f \in C(X)$ then for every $\epsilon >0$ exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \left \| f_k -f \right \|_u := \sup_{x \in X} |f_k -f| < \epsilon $, then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ if $x \notin \mathrm{supp}(f_k)$, i.e. $f \in C_0(X)$. Conversely, if $f \in C_0(X)$, let the compacts $K_n=\lbrace x \in X : |f(x)| \leq 1/n \rbrace$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Correspondingly to such compact there are functions $g_n \in C_c(X)$ with $0 \leq g_n \leq 1$ and $g_n=1$ on $K_n$. 
Then we define $f_n:=g_n f$, it's clear that $f_n \in C_c(X)$ and also $\left \| f_n -f \right \|_u < 1/n$, therefore $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $X$.

Note that we used substantially the fact that the $N_2$ (i.e. admits countable bases) - locally Hausdorff compact spaces - admit an exhaustive of compacts and in correspondence can be chosen of the Urysohn's function. This hypothesis has been replaced with the fact that the space $X$ is $\sigma-$compact, so it is not required that it is also $N_2$.

Comment: The $L^\infty$ norm is essential supremum, not supremum. Thus we only have uniformly convergence almost everywhere. The problem is how to deal with the null-set in which $f_n$ may not converges.

Comment: Yes but here the functions considered are continuous and $\left \| \cdot \right \|_u = \left \| \cdot \right \|_\infty$

Comment: It seems that if you assume that $f_k \to f$ with $f \in C(X)$, then you are presupposing $f$ is continuous, which is an uncertainty of the original post.

Comment: The uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous

Comment: @Tom Does converging in the $L^\infty$ norm preserve continuity? The null-sets are annoying.

Comment: Xiang Yu, we have $\left \| f_n -f \right \|_\infty \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $A \subset X $ with $\mu (X \setminus A) = 0$

Comment: @JohnMartin So you can only say that $f$ is continuous on $A$, but this doesn't mean $f$ is continuous on $X$.

Comment: @XiangYu, I edited the answer, it should work now

Comment: @JohnMartin We may assume that every open set has positive measure, under this assumption, it is easier to prove the claim. But I don't think the assumption is true in all locally compact Hasudroff spaces with Randon measure.

Comment: This assumption can be justified by the following theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: @JohnMartin I don't see why the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem implies that every open set in a LCH space has positive measure, could you say it more clearly? Thanks

Comment: @XiangYu, basically because in $X$ you can consider regular Borel measures (inner and outer regular) and an open is approximated from interior with compact sets or from the outside with Borel sets. In particular, Radon measures can be introduced as linear functionals $g \in C_c(X) \mapsto \int_X g d\mu \geq 0$ where $\mu$ is an arbitrary Borel measure on $X$.